# LATEX Custom Section Name Mod

Tags: sectioning

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\titleformat{\section}         
  {\scshape\raggedright} 
\begin{document}

\section*{test}
I specified how I wish for the section titles to appear. However I wish to be able to specify not to use all capitals for some. Here I wish the section title to just be 'Test'


\section*{testing}
* Z This is a good section title but I am wondering how can I get the text line to return after to line up to 'Z' instead of '*'

\end{document}
```

I learned how to customize how to present the section however after doing that I wonder is it possible to modify specific sections. Say if I want them all to be smallcaps like shown with the exception of a few.

My second question is in \section*{testing} and I wonder how to get the second line and all others to line up under 'Z' instead of '*'

Comment: If you input the title all caps, you need not use `\scshape`, that does nothing at all.

Comment: Your example does not compile

Comment: @egreg thank you I updated

Comment: @DG  thank you I updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility: for the first point, I defined with `etoolbox` a new boolean, `nosc` (false by default), and use the `\iftoggle` command for the section formatting.

For the second point, I used an `itemize` environment, with parameters set with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{nosc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}
  {\iftoggle{nosc}{\raggedright}{\raggedright\scshape}}

\begin{document}

\toggletrue{nosc}
\section*{Test}
I specified how I wish for the section titles to appear. However I wish to be able to specify not to use all capitals for some. Here I wish the section title to just be 'Test'
\togglefalse{nosc}

\section*{Testing again}
\begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep]
\item[*] Z This is a good section title but I am wondering how can I get the text line to return after to line up to 'Z' instead of '*'
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

With the advanced interface, use this code for  `\titleformat`:

```
\titleformat{\section} {\HUGE\iftoggle{nosc}{}{\scshape}\filright} {}{0em} {} [\titlerule\togglefalse{nosc}]
```

You won't have to revert back to `\togglefalse` by hand, as it is incorporated at the end of the code.

Comment: this is so perfect thank you. i try to modify to add underline but it does not work in this approach :\titleformat{\section}         
  {\HUGE\scshape\raggedright} 
  {}{0em}                      
  {}                           
  [\titlerule]

Comment: Please see my edit. B.t.w., are you really using the `\HUGE` command for the size of section titles?